# How does the following representation of $\mathbb{C}l(3)$ decompose into irreducibles?

Tags: representation-theory, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry, graded-algebras

Consider the three dimensional complex Clifford algebra $\mathbb{C}l(3)$ and the following representation
$$S=\text{Span}\{|0\rangle,c^\dagger|0\rangle,\gamma^3|0\rangle,\gamma^3c^\dagger|0\rangle\},$$
where $c=\partial/\partial c^\dagger$ (with $c$ and $\gamma^3$ anticommuting variables) and $(\gamma^3)^2=1$. This furnishes a four dimensional representation by
$$\gamma^1=c^\dagger+c$$
and
$$\gamma^2=-i(c^\dagger-c).$$
But $\mathbb{C}l(3)$ has a unique irreducible representation, and it happens to be two dimensional. How can I express $S$ as a direct sum of two copies of this irrep?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to play around a bit and found the decomposition! It is
$$S=\text{Span}\{|0\rangle+\gamma^3|0\rangle,c^\dagger|0\rangle-\gamma^3c^\dagger|0\rangle\}\oplus\text{Span}\{|0\rangle-\gamma^3|0\rangle,c^\dagger|0\rangle+\gamma^3c^\dagger|0\rangle\}$$